# googletest in eclipse broke down

Tags: eclipse, unit-testing, googletest

Here is what the console said.. broke down when I ran that unit test alone. seems to be memory issue, but it was ok when I ran all the unit tests together.. strange.. i wonder if anyone else has seen and fixed this issue before. thanks in advance.

```
The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian) 
[New Thread 7040.0x1bf0] 
[New Thread 7040.0xcac] 
[New Thread 7040.0x1bfc] 
../../../../src/gdb-7.6/gdb/utils.c:1162: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 1684217900 bytes. 
A problem internal to GDB has been detected, further debugging may prove unreliable. 
Quit this debugging session?  
This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way. 
Please contact the application's support team for more information. (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal] 
../../../../src/gdb-7.6/gdb/utils.c:1162: internal-error: virtual memory exhausted: can't allocate 1684217900 bytes. 
A problem internal to GDB has been detected, further debugging may prove unreliable. Create a core file of GDB? (y or n) [answered Y; input not from terminal]
```

[image]

Comment: What happens when you run the same unit-test alone *not* under GDB?

Answer (score 0):

By very lousy luck, you have fallen foul of [open (reopened) bug #9232 in GDB](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=9232)

Comment: I don't think so. A debugger will do things at a breakpoint that it doesn't do elsewhere. Breakpoints are user-inputs to the debugger; different breakpoints are different inputs.